# error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol in C++ with Node-Gyp

Tags: c++, node.js, json, node-gyp

Hello I am new to C++ and have been building an addon for one of my programs using node-gyp. However, when I try to build the addon I run into this error:

```
watercpp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class std::basic_istr
eam<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __cdecl Json::operator>>(class std::
basic_istream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,class Json::Value &)" (??5
Json@@YAAEAV?$basic_istream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@AEAV12@AEAVValue@0@@Z)
```

I believe it has to do with reference errors accessing info from a JSON. This is what my code looks like:

```
#include "node.h"
#include "node_buffer.h"
#include "v8.h"
#include <value.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <json/json.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace v8;
using namespace std;

namespace water{
    using v8::FunctionCallbackInfo;
    using v8::Isolate;
    using v8::Local;
    using v8::Object;
    using v8::String;
    using v8::Number;
    using v8::Value;
    using v8::Array;

    void water(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value> &args)
    {
        Json::Value waterjson;
        std::ifstream people_file("waterjson.json", std::ifstream::binary);
        people_file >> waterjson;
        Local<Array> a;
        Local<Array> b;
        if(args[0]->IsArray())
        {
           a = args[0].As<Array>();
           b = args[1].As<Array>();
        }
        int total=0;
        for(std::size_t i=0; i<a->Length(); i++)
        {
            v8::Isolate* isolate = args.GetIsolate();
            v8::String::Utf8Value atr(isolate, a->Get(i));
            std::string cppStr(*atr);

            int c = waterjson[cppStr]["content"].asInt();
            int s = waterjson[cppStr]["serving"].asInt();
            int m = s/100;
            int amount = c*m;
            v8::String::Utf8Value btr(isolate, b->Get(i));
            std::string cppNum(*btr);
            int num = stoi(cppNum);
            total+=(amount*num);
        }

        args.GetReturnValue().Set(total);
    }
    
    void Initialize(Local<Object> exports)
    {
        NODE_SET_METHOD(exports, "water", water);
    }
    NODE_MODULE(NODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME, Initialize)
}
```

I am not sure on what to do as I've never seen an error like this before and there is little documentation online on how to deal with it. Thank you!

This is my binding.gyp:

```
{
    "targets":[
        {
            "target_name": "water",
            "sources": ["watercpp.cpp"],
            "include_dirs": [
                "./vcpkg/installed/x86-windows/include",
                "./vcpkg/buildtrees/jsoncpp/src/1.9.2-d01d7f5c9b.clean/include/json",
            ],
            "library_dirs":[
                "./vcpkg/buildtrees/jsoncpp/x86-windows-dbg/src/lib_json",
                "./vcpkg/installed/x86-windows/lib", "./vcpkg/packages/jsoncpp_x86-windows/lib",
            ],
            "libraries":[
                "-ljsoncpp.lib", "<(module_root_dir)/vcpkg/buildtrees/jsoncpp/x86-windows-dbg/src/lib_json",
                "<(module_root_dir)/vcpkg/installed/x86-windows/lib", "<(module_root_dir)/vcpkg/packages/jsoncpp_x86-windows/lib",


            ],
        },
    ]
}
```

Comment: What is the name of the json library you are using?

Comment: Reading the error message: *LNK2001: unresolved external symbol* linker problem, so the program compiles. The missing item is declared, but not defined.  *"class std::basic_istr
eam<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __cdecl Json::operator>>(class std::
basic_istream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,class Json::Value &)"* Could not find an operator overload for `>>` that is a member of `Json` , presumably a namespace, that takes an`istream &` and a `Json::value`& and returns an `istream &`. Is there a library that goes with json.h that needs to be added to the linker arguments?

Comment: It looks like you could be using [jsoncpp](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp) and in that case you should probably add `libjsoncpp.lib` (or `libjsoncpp.dll`) to your project (the linking phase).

Comment: @user4581301 I am using jsoncpp as my library in order to read my json file.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I would add that library to my binding.gyp file?

Comment: @RDK961 I have no idea how `node-gyp` works I'm afraid. First check if `libjsoncpp.lib` exists in your `jsoncpp` installation. Do you have a makefile of some sort? Is that what `binding.gyp` is?

Comment: @TedLyngmo In my installed folder I do have jsoncpp.lib. Is that what I need to reference? And yes binding.gyp is used with node-gyp for the C++ addon.

Comment: Ok, that sounds promising. See if there is a section for linking or libraries. If the `binding.gyp` file is a pure text file and it isn't too big, you could put it in the question.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the `jsoncpp` library to the linking phase in `binding.gyp`:

```
"libraries": [
  "-L.", "-ljsoncpp"
],
```

- `-L<libdir>` - The directory to look for the library in. Replace `.` with the actual path if it's not in your current directory.
- `-l<library>` - The actual library to link with. You may want to specify the full static library name `jsoncpp.lib` instead to avoid problems if `jsoncpp.dll` exists too.

Comment: This seems to be working, except now I run into the problem of: LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'jsoncpp.lib'

Comment: @RDK961 Is the file `jsoncpp.lib` in the same directory as `binding.gyp`? Put the complete `binding.gyp` file in the question ([edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63383329/edit)) so I can see how the other paths look.

Comment: No they are not in the same directory, I added the binding.gyp file into the question. There are also multiple directories that I find the jsoncpp.lib file in and I am not sure on which one to use.

Comment: @RDK961 "`"./vcpkg/buildtrees/jsoncpp/src/1.9.2-d01d7f5c9b.clean/include/json"` looks like a relative path to the source code. Do you find `jsoncpp.lib` in the `./vcpkg` directory tree somewhere? If so, that's the directory path you need. I don't understand what `<(module_root_dir)` means. Is that some special thing for`gyp`?

The entry in the `library_dirs` array seems to be missing the `.` before `/vcpkg/...`. Did you add that entry manually?

Comment: `"./vcpkg/buildtrees/jsoncpp/src/1.9.2-d01d7f5c9b.clean/include/json"` is used for the C++ file so that it knows where the json.h header file is. `jsoncpp.lib` is in multiple paths in the `./vcpkg` directory tree. And I added the `<(module_root_dir)` because when I used -L I get the error `LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option '/L.\vcpkg\buildtrees\jsoncpp\x86-windows-dbg\src\lib_json.lib'` And my bad I forgot to add the `.`

Comment: I understand what the `include_dirs` array does, but it looks funny that it's a source code tree instread of how it usually looks with installed packages. So, the library is found in `./vcpkg/buildtrees/jsoncpp/x86-windows-dbg/src/lib_json` then I guess?

Comment: Yes it is found in there but it is also found in multiple other places and I am unsure of which to use.

Comment: Ok, add the path to all the places you find it in to the question too and I'll see if I can figure it out. Btw, did you compile the jsoncpp library yourself?

Comment: Okay I added all the paths and updated the binding.gyp in the question. And no, I used the vcpkg installer to install it.

Comment: Ok...  and you still get exactly the same message `LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'jsoncpp.lib'`? What if you compile by hand and add the path to the library on the command line?

Comment: I'm sorry, I am new to C++. I will figure out how to go about doing that and let you know how it goes.